# Will shortening a URL hurt my SEO?

Tags: seo, url-rewriting

Will I mess up my SEO if I remove a part of my URL, even if it still takes you to the same page?

An example is:

`example.com/services/nc/clt/charlotte-nc/...`

And I want to take out the "services" folder as well as the "nc" folder to shorten the URL to this:

`example.com/clt/charlotte-nc/...`

They both lead to the same page (I don't know why though). I have some backlinks currently to the current URL, will I lose their juice if I change the URL?

Comment: You could change the url but do proper redirection from htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

Proper use of rel="canonical" meta tag will not let you reduce your SERP rank.
Read more [here](https://moz.com/learn/seo/canonicalization)

Answer (score 1):

Use a proper 301 redirection. Read more about it on [MoZ article here:](https://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection) A 301 redirect is a permanent redirect which passes between 90-99% of link juice (ranking power) to the redirected page.

Answer (score 1):

> Will I mess up my SEO if I remove a part of my URL, even if it still
>   takes you to the same page?

YES, because this will become a new URL unless you apply a proper `301` redirection. It can still pass on the link juice, but there will be traction and it should be right back on track as long as the meta data, content, etc... are intact.

However, I do suggest having the keywords in the URL still (not to the extent that will be an exact match). As a side note, I do think that the first URL looks spammy with too many geo-modifiers.